# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors for matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A=[1 4]
      [2 3]
Find all eigenvalues of A and for each eigenvalue give an eigenvector.  choose one of the eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs for A, (a, b) (That is Ab=ab) and let P(x)=x^3-5x^2+2x+9.  Evaluate P(A)b, that is, apply the matrix P(A) to the eigenvector b.

I found one of the pairs that I wanted to use for the second part to be:
eigenvalue=5
eigenvector: [1,1]

How do I use this information to  evaluate P(A)b?  Do I input the eigenvalue of 5 into P(x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The reason you can do that is the following:

$A^2b=AAb=A5b=5Ab=25b$.

You can do the same for the whole polynomial, and $(A^3-5A^2+2A+9)b=(5^3-5.5^2+2.5+9)b$

So you don't need to calculate the matrix $A^3-5A62+2A+9I$